# HOW TO capture ingoing packets from ASP.NET MVC WEB API CONTROLLER

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, asp.net-web-api, http-post, wireshark

I have an ASP.NET MVC WEB API Controller published on IIS which is listening for incoming HTTP requests:

```
System.IO.Stream req = Request.InputStream;
req.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
string dataJson = new System.IO.StreamReader(req).ReadToEnd();
```

Note: Request is from System.Web.Mvc assembly

This Web API Controller always expects to receive a JSON file.

This Web API is in production and it is currently not making any log to trace the JSON content received. I need to capture this JSON file to see its content.
Since I cannot debug it in production I have thought to capture the JSON file content using WireShark.
How can I do it?

Comment: Do you need to log just the incoming JSON or the entire request object? Have you considered writing the request in a file? log4net is a good one for that. Not sure why you are considering WireShark for.

Comment: Yes you can use either Wireshark or Fiddler.@Rahatur, he does not want to update code on production at the moment!

Comment: @Rahatur The reason is what Mukesh says.

Comment: @MukeshModhvadiya How can I do it?

Comment: The question states that he is unable to debug not deploy. The question needs to be updated accordingly. Also are there multiple sites hosted on production? If yes then how does he confire WireShark on production?